# AutoHotKey How to get date from a string with Regex

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have a string like this:

> "NEW.APPLICATION SENT TO OFFICE A 2/2/16-COMPLETED"

Is there a way to use Regex in Autohotkey to extract the date as 02/02/2016? I started by trying to match the `/` symbol, and then get the digits before or after it.

```
myString := "NEW.APPLICATION SENT TO OFFICE A 2/2/16-COMPLETED"
FoundPos := RegExMatch(myString, "\/")
myString := SubStr(myString, (FoundPos -3),(FoundPos+8))
myString := RegExReplace(myString, "\D", "") ; This remove more than I wanted
```

But I don't know how to get the date or months. Sometimes they might have spaces in between like this as well. `"02 /02/16"`

Comment: If it's a fairly normal regex engine, you could use `(\d+)\s*/\s*(\d+)\s*/\s*(\d+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to match a pattern like this:
`number (space) slash (space) number (space) slash (space) number`

```
myString := "NEW.APPLICATION SENT TO OFFICE A 2 / 02 / 16-COMPLETED"

;This would do the job for the matching:
RegexMatch(myString, "(\d+)\s*/\s*(\d+)\s*/\s*(\d+)", match)
MsgBox, %match1%/%match2%/%match3%

;I prefer giving the regex results names though:
RegexMatch(myString, "O)(?P<month>\d+)\s*/\s*(?P<day>\d+)\s*/\s*(?P<year>\d+)", match)
MsgBox, % match.month "/" match.day "/" match.year

;now we just need to add zeroes in front of the day/month in case they are single digit
month := StrLen(match.month)=1 ? "0" match.month : match.month ;if single digit add a zero to the beginning, otherwise don't change it
day := StrLen(match.day)=1 ? "0" match.day : match.day ;if single digit add a zero to the beginning, otherwise don't change it
year := StrLen(match.year)=2 ? "20" match.year : match.year ;if year has only 2 digits add a 20 to the beginning

finalDate = %month%/%day%/%year%

MsgBox, %finalDate% ;output is 02/02/2016
```

I tested it and it works with pretty much anything:
`2 / 02 / 16`, `2 / 02 /2016` `2 /2/ 16`, `02/2/16`, `2/2/ 16`, `2/02 / 2016`, etc etc. The output is always `02/02/2016`

**edit**:
To replace the date in the original string just add this line:

```
myString := RegexReplace(myString, "\d+\s*/\s*\d+\s*/\s*\d+", finalDate)
MsgBox, %myString%
```

Comment: This is a very impressive answer, I was wondering how to store the month, date and year into variables. Now I can see it from your example!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very restrictive regex according to your requirements:

```
(?:^|[^0-9])([0-2]?[1-9]|[1-3]0|31) *\/ *(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]) *\/ *((?:20)?[0-9]{2})(?:$|[^0-9])
```